# Vue 3 set ref value inside function

Tags: vue.js

I have value 'reset', that should be set to false when file is uploaded. After fileUpload function is triggered, 'reset' is still 'true' (it is set to 'true' externally), how to set it to 'false' on file upload?

```
<template>
  reset: {{reset}}<br> // should display variable here
  <div class="fileDnd m0"">
    <label for="fileUploaderInput" class="">
    </label>
    <input
      type="file"
      name="fileUploaderInput"
      @input="fileUpload"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, toRefs } from "@vue/reactivity";
export default {
  name: "Upload",
  props: {
    reset: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  emits: ["upload"],
  setup(props, { emit }) {
    const { reset } = toRefs(props);
    const fileNames = ref("");

    function fileUpload(event) {
      reset.value = false;// should be set here
      const files = event.target.files;

      emit("upload", files);
    }

    return {
      fileNames,
      fileUpload,
      reset,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: `props` are passed in from the parent, and shouldn't really be changed in the child. If you want something to modify locally, you should use a variable instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since that `reset` is a prop, it should be updated inside the parent component inside the `upload` event handler :

```js
uploadHandler(files){
 
//update the reset here
}
```

or you could create a ref that takes the `reset` prop as initial value, then update it as you did above